# in linux command line mysql script not logging to file

Tags: mysql, logging

I am trying to setup a Jenkins process for rebuilding the ddl and dml for a mysql db running on an lubuntu server. The bash script executes a call to mysql setting a log file and then I run awk to analyze the results to see if any errors occur. However the call to mysql, though it is rebuilding the database does not output anything to the log file. I have tried to different variants for the problem:

```
mysql --user=<usr> --password=<pwd> <ddl.sql >ddl.log
```

and

```
mysql --user=<usr> --password=<pwd> --tee=ddl.log ddl.sql
```

In both instances the log remains 0 in length. if I run mysql interactively and enter:

```
\T ddl.log
\. ddl.sql
```

then the ddl results show up in the log. I was wondering what I might be doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Probably a permissions problem on the file, or you're running the script in a different directory than you expect.  Try using "/tmp/ddl.log" as your output file.

Comment: I am running this as root so I have full permissions to everything.  the log files gets created but it is empty.

Comment: Well, I can't help you with your problem (@Barmar's answer seems pertinent) but you really need to get out of the habit of doing things as root.  It's dangerous.

Comment: Do you get output if you don't redirect to a file?

Comment: No, there is no output at all then

Answer (score 1):

By default, when `mysql` is run in batch mode, the only output it produces is the query results, not all the informative messages that are produced in interactive mode. You can get increasing levels of verbosity by using the `-v` option one or more times.

Answer (score -1):

Just redirect output stream to file `$ program-name > ddl.log` http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/redirecting-stderr-to-stdout/

Comment: This is what I am doing in the examples already.  again the log file is created but is 0 in length